# multiply value daily php

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I'm trying to make a script which penalizes a user daily after a time stamp. 
For the first day, it will penalize 1 point, second day 2 points, third 4 points, fourth 8 point, 16, 32, 64 and so on.

How would I go about auto generating a strtotime and the multiplications?

I really don't even know what i'm looking for is called at this point which makes searching hard, sorry if this has been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose, that $timestamp1 is the first day timestamp and the $timestamp2 is now timestamp. Then:

```
$difference = abs(strtotime($timestamp2)-strtotime($timestamp1));

$days = floor($difference / (60*60*24));
$penalty = pow(2,$days);

echo "{$days} left, so your penalty is: {$penalty}";
```

Sample results:

```
0 left, so your penalty is: 1
1 left, so your penalty is: 2
2 left, so your penalty is: 4
3 left, so your penalty is: 8
4 left, so your penalty is: 16
5 left, so your penalty is: 32
6 left, so your penalty is: 64
...
```

Comment: These are both excellent answers. Have to go with this one though.

Comment: how would I input each into a mysql string dynamically?

Comment: or rather, how would I initiate it only once daily?

Comment: If you want to run some code ones a day, then you should uss **CRON**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$initial_date     = '2012-10-20';
$initial_datetime = new DateTime($initial_date);
$today_datetime   = new DateTime();
$days_passed      = $initial_datetime->diff($today_datetime)->format('%a');
$penalty          = pow(2, ($days_passed-1));
echo $penalty;
```